# Hide FTP credentials from code .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

I have an application that needs to upload a file to my FTP server, but I noticed that anybody could decompile that app and get the FTP's user and password.
The code is this:

```
                            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                            {
                                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpuser", "ftppassword");
                                client.UploadFile("ftp://ip/" + Computer + "_" + ExecTime + ".txt", "STOR", Application.StartupPath + @"\Stats.txt");
                            }
```

And I would like to hide those credentials from anyone. How could this be done?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. You can't have secrets on the client computer. Anything is visible. You can only make it hard to find - by obfuscating it. But that doesn't help when you use FTP since that sends the password in clear text and it's super easy to intercept.

Comment: The best option would probably be to give each user their own username and password.

Comment: Recommendations: Don't use FTP, use HTTP file upload. Have HTTP server perform whatever authentication/checks you want, including checking the file is valid type/size checking for viruses. It's easy to add logic to HTTP upload, FTP not so much.

Answer (score 1):

It might be wiser to implement public FTP with no credentials and very limited access only to the resources you want. Obfuscation won't work since someone will de-obfuscate it anyway. Since you want to upload files from the client you may want to put some sort of controller so the upload mechanism can't be abused.
Or... simply give each user an account with limited access and problem sorted :).
I think this is more of a design problem :)